# How to save changes on Opportunity from other screen?

Tags: c#, .net, acumatica

I have a field in CROpportunity named UsrOrderTotalValue.
Sales Order(SO301000) and Opportunitis(CR304000) are linked with added to SOOrder tab custome field UsrOpportunityID.
When Save Button pusshed on Sales Order, it's needed to save to a UsrOrderTotalValue some Value.
Some code snipet is given below. 
Besides below I tried different approaches of using Persist, but nothing works.
My Acumatica version:
Acumatica 2018 R1 (18.110.0017)

```
OpportunityMaint opportunityGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<OpportunityMaint>();
SOOrderExt sOOrderExt = row.GetExtension<SOOrderExt>();
CROpportunity cROpportunity = Opportunity.Select(sOOrderExt.UsrOpportunityID);

opportunityGraph.Opportunity.Update(cROpportunity);
opportunityGraph.Save.Press();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below, I have hardcoded value, please replace with your fields.

```
    [PXOverride]
    public void Persist(Action del)
    {
        if ((Base.Document.Cache.GetStatus(Base.Document.Current) == PXEntryStatus.Inserted || Base.Document.Cache.GetStatus(Base.Document.Current) == PXEntryStatus.Updated))
        {
            OpportunityMaint opportunityGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<OpportunityMaint>();
            CROpportunity cROpportunity = new CROpportunity();

            cROpportunity.OpportunityID = "000001";
            cROpportunity = opportunityGraph.Opportunity.Current = opportunityGraph.Opportunity.Select(cROpportunity);

            if (cROpportunity != null)
                cROpportunity.OpportunityName = "test";

            opportunityGraph.Opportunity.Update(cROpportunity);
            opportunityGraph.Save.Press();
        }
        del();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for answer @John!
This approach gives me an error: 'Acquisition Type' cannot be empty.
Trace points me to `opportunityGraph.Save.Press();`
Important thing to mention - I need to save changes to a custom field on Opportunity:
`cROpportunityExt.UsrOrderTotalValue = orderTotal;`